# how to serialize/deserialize content in RAMDirectory in Lucene.Net

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

In our scenario, IO operation is restricted and index building and serving are in different processes.

We consider to leverage RAMDirectory to build/serve index. The gap is that we need to persist(serialize) content in RAMDirectory and deserialize it when serving.

Answer (score 1):

We need to subclass RAMDirectory and RAMFile. More detail can be found at [Extend Lucene](https://github.com/jiangjianliang/Examples/tree/master/ExtendLucene)